# Multiband virtual raster with gdalbuildvrt: Control how bands are sorted

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalbuildvrt

I am making a multiband virtual raster using gdalbuildvrt. Everything works fine, but a little detail remains annoying: I cannot control how the bands are sorted. I specified the input raster using the -input_file_list option, but the order is not kept by gdalbuildvrt. Instead it sort the band with lexicographic sorting, which is not what I want.

For instance, that would be my input file list:

```
/home/example/rasters/1634.tif
/home/example/rasters/5899.tif
/home/example/rasters/15680.tif
```

I'd  like to have a vrt corresponding to:

```
band 1 -> 1634.tif
band 2 -> 5899.tif
band 3 -> 15680.tif
```

But instead I get:

```
band 1 -> 15680.tif
band 2 -> 1634.tif
band 3 -> 5899.tif
```

I could manually rearange things, but I'd like to avoid it if there is any cleaner solution...

So my question is: is there a way to control how gdalbuildvrt sort the bands when creating a multiband virtual raster?

Comment: A workaround could be to create a new sorted vrt with gdaltranslate and -b parameters.

Comment: The problem here is that I have 679 bands...

Comment: How about renaming source images so that they will be sorted as you wish by using vrt files? Should be possible to automate with a script that adds leading zeroes.

Comment: Well, of course it is a possible workaround, but my question was more about if there is a way to do it within gdal, in order to avoid using this kind of workaround. But apparently there is not. Thank's!

Comment: Gdalbuildvrt utility is based on an older gdalvrtmerge.py script. The script should still be available from GDAL sources. Perhaps it could be edited to sort files differently.