# Controlling grids assigned to multiband QGIS Virtual Raster

Tags: qgis, virtual-raster

I see this has been asked 4 years ago but I see no useful answer for me

[Multiband virtual raster with gdalbuildvrt: Control how bands are sorted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201364/multiband-virtual-raster-with-gdalbuildvrt-control-how-bands-are-sorted)

I do not understand how to control the RGB assignation order and what the end result is.

Using Virtual Raster to build an RGB and I cannot control which grid becomes which band. I cannot work out which grid ended up where because statistics in the 3 band VRT do not resemble those of the grids. I cannot tell going in because the Multiple Selection windows often lists a different order to the Layers window, which can be different to the alphabetical order.

Which grid goes where in an RGB is incredibly important in radiometrics but QGIS appears to be random in this case.

Please tell me I am wrong and how to do it.